# Convert mm-yyyy to datetime datatype in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert a datetime datatype of the form 24/12/2021  07:24:00 to mm-yyyy format which is 12-2021 with datetime datatype. I need the mm-yyyy in datetime format in order to sort the column 'Month-Year' in a time series. I have tried

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_excel('abc.xlsx')


df['Month-Year'] = df['Due Date'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%m-%y'))
df.set_index(['ID', 'Month-Year'], inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df
```

The column 'Month-Year' does not sort in time series because 'Month-Year' is of object datatype. How do I please convert 'Month-Year' column to datetime datatype?

Comment: side note, it's `%Y` for 4-digit year ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to obtain a solution to the problem.

```py
df['month_year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Due Date']).dt.to_period('M')
```

I got this from the link below

https://www.interviewqs.com/ddi-code-snippets/extract-month-year-pandas

Answer (score 0):

`df['Month-Year']=pd.to_datetime(df['Month-Year']).dt.normalize()`

will convert the Month-Year to `datetime64[ns]`.

Use it before sorting.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I did tried this and it converted the Month-Year to datetime64[ns] but it also changed 12-2021 to 2021-12-01. How can I fix this please?

Comment: After sorting you can use your formula to convert it back to `mm-yyyy format`. Your formula `df['Month-Year'] = df['Due Date'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%m-%y'))` looks good.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I tried to convert it back but the 'Month-Year' is already an index and so I got this error KeyError: 'Month-Year'

Comment: If `Month-Year`  is an index in your dataframe, you can first convert it into a column by `df['Month-Year'] = df.index`  , it will convert your index to a column.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That gave me the error 'ValueError: MultiIndex has no single backing array. Use 'MultiIndex.to_numpy()' to get a NumPy array of tuples.' I apologise for my mistake. I converted 'ID' and 'Month-Year' into indices from the main code above not 'Due Date'. I have edited the code.